# "Group by" on a solr field using solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using SOLR 2.5.1

I have a field `type`. I am querying using SOLR Java driver.  I am only fetching `type` field in the query.

*Note: query field and fl (`type` in my case)  are different*

Say response is something like

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 200,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "type": "A"
      },
        {
        "type": "B"
      },
       {
        "type": "A"
      },
        {
        "type": "A"
      },
       {
        "type": "C"
      },
       {
        "type": "D"
      },
       {
        "type": "A"
      },
       {
        "type": "B"
      },
       {
        "type": "C"
      },
       {
        "type": "B"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to group output and find the count of occurrence. Output like:

```
"A":4, "B":3, "C":2, "D":1
```

I can process it in java code. But is there any way to group and count on a particular field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html) and gives you a count for each indexed term into the field. It is important that each term is kept as a single token if you want to generate counts for the complete text (i.e. you want to count `New York` and not `New` and `York`). A string field is usually well suited as a field type to facet on.

For the SolrJ integration, you use `.addFacetField("type")` in your query, and then you can use `getFacetField("type")` on the response object.

Comment: I am querying on a different field and emitting different field (`type`) in above example. Is that possible via *faceting*?

Comment: Yes. Faceting doesn't depend on which field you're querying, only the field in the set of documents returned by the query.